# Gelfand spectrum as a measure space

Tags: measure-theory, banach-algebras

Given a Lebesgue probability measure space $(X,m)$ (say, just the unit interval with the Lebesgue measure on it), let $A$ be a closed subalgebra of the real $L^\infty(X,m)$. Then one can realize the complexification of $A$ as the algebra of continuous functions $C(S)$ on its Gelfand spectrum $S$, and the measure $m$ induces a measure $\mu$ on $S$. Under what condition on $A$ are the (completed) measure spaces $(X,m)$ and $(S,\mu)$ naturally isomorphic (i.e., their isomorphism preserves the integrals of the functions from $A$)? Is it enough to require that $A$ separate points in $X$?

What I have in mind is the situation when $X$ is compact with $\text{supp}\,m=X$, so that $C(X)$ is embedded into $L^\infty(X,m)$, and $A$ is just $C(X)$. Then, obviously, $S=X$ and $\mu=m$. I would like to have a description of this situation just in terms of $A$ as a subalgebra of $L^\infty(X,m)$.

Comment: Is $A$ selfadjoint? (I'm wondering why $A$ should be algebra-isomorphic to $C(S)$.)

Comment: Sorry - I should have specified that I am only interested in real spaces - I will edit the question.

Comment: What do you mean by wanting $(X,m)$ and $(S,\mu)$ to be "isomorphic"?  For instance if $X = \mathbb{N}$ with counting measure and $A = L^\infty$ itself (which certainly separates points), then $S = \beta \mathbb{N}$ is the Stone-Cech compactification, right?  In what sense is $\beta \mathbb{N}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge - Thank you - there are indeed some implied assumptions. First of all, I should have made more explicit that I am talking about probability spaces. As for the isomorphism - let us say that I want $L^\infty(X,m)$ and $L^\infty(S,\mu)$ to be isomorphic as Banach algebras with a common subalgebra $A$. In the example with $\mathbb N$ the measure $\mu$ is still a discrete measure. What I have in mind is the situation when $X$ is compact with $\text{supp}\,m=X$, and $A=C(X)$ - I want to describe this situation in terms of $A$ as a subalgebra of $L^\infty(X,m)$.

Comment: The answer to the question is surely that this happens if and only if $A$ is weak* dense in $L^\infty(X)$. I'm not writing this as an answer because there are a lot of things to check and I don't have time to do this.

Comment: Let me echo Nik's comment: iff $A$ is weak* dense in $L^\infty(X)$. I believe you can find details somewhere in Takasaki's book(s), but I don't have it handy. The main thing is: every $L^\infty$-function on the Gelfand spectrum of $L^\infty(X)$ is continuous. Look for the term "hyperstonean space" in the index...

Comment: @Nik Weaver - Many thanks! This is what I was looking for.